# validity of variables in foreach and if loops

Tags: c#

I am trying to put together custom title elements for form input labels.

I need to insert this into a foreach loop, this is what I have tried so far but my variable `title` when placed in my `label` element, contains no data:

```
string title;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var defaultCheckedString = Model.GetDefaultSelectedString(item);
            var checkedString = string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultCheckedString) ? string.Empty : "checked";

            if (item.Caption == "extend")
            {
                title = "some custom text";
            }
    %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label title="<%: title %>" class="control-label col-sm-10 roi-label"><%: item.Caption %></label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
            <% if(Model.AllowMultiSelect) { %>
            <input type="checkbox" roilabel="<%: formElement.SourceContent.Name %>" name="<%: formElement.ElementName %>" value="<%: item.Value %>" class="form-control FormChoice__Input FormChoice__Input--Checkbox" <%: checkedString %> <%: defaultCheckedString %> data-f-datainput />
            <% } else  { %>
            <input type="radio" roiname="<%: formElement.SourceContent.Name %>" name="<%: formElement.ElementName %>" value="<%: item.Value %>" class="form-control FormChoice__Input FormChoice__Input--Radio" <%: checkedString %> <%: defaultCheckedString %> data-f-datainput />
            <% } %>

            </div>
    </div>

    <% } %>
```

**Update 1 :**

In Visual Studio, if I mouse-over the `title` variable which I have placed in the `label` tag I get the following message:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'title'

[image]

Comment: Seems like either your `items`-collection does not contain any elements at all, or at least none with `Caption == "extend"`.

Comment: You're only setting a title on items that are extended.  Caption will also depend on the content of item..  Are you sure items contains what you thought?

Comment: Change `string title;` to `string title = string.Empty;`